# Статические методы у не статических классов

Tags: c#, .net, static

Есть классы, которые наследуются от одного абстрактного класса, у которого есть не виртуальная функция для работы со строкой:

```
protected string NormalizeString(string s)
{
    return s.Trim().ToUpper();
}
```

Нужно ли эту функцию делать статической? Когда функции нужно делать статическими, а когда обычными, если они не используют поля объекта?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Да, я бы сделал эту функцию статической.
2. Принцип очень простой.

   - Если функция относится к конкретному объекту, она должна быть нестатической. Пример: получение температуры с конкретного термометра — явно нестатическая фукция.
   - Если функция относится ко всем объектам данного типа, то она скорее всего должна быть статической. Пример: получение диапазона температур для класса термометров — явно статическая функция.
   - Если функция не относится ни к какому объекту, то есть является по существу утилитой (как у вас), и не сильно связана с функциональностью класса, её надо бы вынести в отдельный статический класс. Но часто, конечно, лень. Пример: перевод температуры из градусов Фаренгейта в градусы Цельсия — явная функция-утилита.

   (Существуют и пограничные случаи, когда не так очевидно, к какому из случаев относится функция. В этих случаях полагайтесь на интуицию или совет более опытных коллег.)

Comment: Я бы добавил, что если функция - утилита, без состояния, напрямую не относится к логике приложения (как у автора), то её можно сделать расширяющим методом и поместить в класс, специально предназначенный для строковых утилит. И ещё неалохо было бы проверить параметр на Null

Comment: @tym32167 проверка на null есть в коде методов, которые вызывают эту функцию перед ее вызовом. Если выносить функцию в отдельный статический класс, то, пожалуй, стоит сделать проверку.

Comment: Пограничный случай хорошо иллюстрирует Equals. И решение довольно простое - статическая + экземплярная реализации, причем экземплярная внутри использует статическую.

Comment: @rdorn: Хороший пример, спасибо!

Comment: @tym32167: Согласен, обычно так и делаю.